# Native Admob ad causing window leak

Tags: android, admob

I am displaying a native ad in an Activity which has FragmentContainerView to display different fragments.
But when I exit the app using back button, I am getting the following error

```
E/WindowManager: android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.status.statusdownload.views.MainActivity has leaked window com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzbft{4119d98 I.E...... ......I. 0,0-840,0} that was originally added here
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:598)
        at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:377)
        at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:96)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzcen.zzh(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@19.8.0:53)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzcdf.zzb(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@19.8.0:134)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzcel.onGlobalLayout(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@19.8.0:108)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzbbl.onGlobalLayout(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@19.8.0:6)
        at android.view.ViewTreeObserver.dispatchOnGlobalLayout(ViewTreeObserver.java:1056)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2629)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1722)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7621)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:1029)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:852)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:787)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:1014)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:235)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7441)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:936)
```

I have destroyed reference to native ad using as per the official documentation (https://developers.google.com/admob/android/native/start)

```
if (isDestroyed) {
                    unifiedNativeAd.destroy()
                    return@forNativeAd
                }
```

Please help me solve this error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like the issue is caused by the new native validator, when I disable the validator in my manifest file the error goes away. Since the validator is automatically disabled for release builds.
Disabling the validator using `NATIVE_AD_DEBUGGER_ENABLED` in the manifest file fixes both these issue.

Answer (score 8):

The accepted answer is correct. But in case if someone doesn't know how should it look in the manifest:

```
<manifest>
  ...
  <application>
    ...
    <meta-data 
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.flag.NATIVE_AD_DEBUGGER_ENABLED"
        android:value="false" />
  </application>
</manifest>
```